# android studio volley web request

Tags: android, android-studio, android-volley

I'm trying to make a get request to an API that returns a JSON array on android studio but when I check the logs it says that there was a problem... (I use kotlin by the way)

What did I do wrong?

here is my code:

```
val url = "http://example.com"
    val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context)

    val jsonArrayRequest = JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
        {
            

            Log.d("notification", "successful request!")
        },
        {
            Log.d("notification", "error on request...")
        })

    queue.add(jsonArrayRequest)
}
```

Comment: Can you please attach your sample response formate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading Techno World's answer I had an idea.
Basically it's the same thing Techno World did but much easier.
What I did is to print the response to the log like this:

```
val url = "http://example.com"
val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context)

val jsonArrayRequest = JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
    {
        Log.d("notification", "successful request!")
    },
    {response ->
        Log.d("notification", "error on request: $response")
    })

queue.add(jsonArrayRequest)
}
```

So when I checked the log I saw this:

```
error on request: com.android.volley.noconnectionerror: java.io.ioexception: cleartext http traffic to example.com not permitted
```

After some research I found out that it was because I used http instead of https. So I changed it and it worked!

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted) is the original question on stack overflow about that error, there are more methods to solve it...

Answer (score 0):

```
var reqParam = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(userName, "UTF-8")
    reqParam += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8")

    val mURL = URL("<Yout API Link>?"+reqParam)

    with(mURL.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection) {
        // optional default is GET
        requestMethod = "GET"

        println("URL : $url")
        println("Response Code : $responseCode")

        BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream)).use {
            val response = StringBuffer()

            var inputLine = it.readLine()
            while (inputLine != null) {
                response.append(inputLine)
                inputLine = it.readLine()
            }
            it.close()
            println("Response : $response")
        }
    }
```

Try this it will help solve your problem..